# How to compare only the month and year between 2 tables in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I try to compare 2 DATE data type between 2 tables in Model section in my codeigniter project. Below is my code in model section:

```
function get_absenand_evaluation_submission_data_by_submission($id){
    
    $data = array();
    if ($this->evaluation_model->get_id_emp_by_subm_id($id))
    {
        $emp_data = $this->evaluation_model->get_id_emp_by_subm_id($id);
        foreach ($emp_data as $row)
            {
                    array_push($data, $row->emp_id);
            }
    }
    
    $this->db->select('e.fname,e.lname,e.nik,e.id, jt.name AS jabatan, ar.nik, ar.nilai', 
        DATEPART (year, 'ar.tanggal') AS 'ar.tahun',
         DATEPART(month, 'ar.tanggal') AS 'ar.bulan',
         DATEPART(year, 'es.date_nilai') AS 'es.tahun',
         DATEPART(month, 'es.date_nilai') AS 'es.bulan',);
    $this->db->from('employment e');
    $this->db->join('employment_job j', 'e.id = j.emp_id', 'INNER');
    $this->db->join('job_title jt', 'j.job_title = jt.id', 'INNER');
    $this->db->join('absen_rekap ar', 'ar.tanggal, ar.nik = e.nik', 'INNER');
    $this->db->join('evaluation_submission es', 'es.date_nilai', 'INNER');
    
    $this->db->where(('ar.tahun', 'es.tahun')&&('ar.bulan', 'es.bulan'));
    $this->db->order_by('e.fname', 'asc');

    if ($data){
        $this->db->where_not_in('e.id',$data);
    }
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return $query->result();
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

I try it, but I get an error. "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'AS' (T_AS) in C:\xampp\htdocs\erp\hrm\models\evaluation_model.php on line 259"

I know, there's an error in my query but I don't have any idea how to fix it. Please help.

Thank you! (:

Okay, I've fix my query like the following code :

```
$this->db->select("e.fname, e.lname, e.nik, e.id, j.emp_id, j.job_title, jt.id, jt.name AS jabatan, ar.nik,
    DATEPART (year, ar.tanggal) AS 'ar.tahun',
     DATEPART(month,ar.tanggal) AS 'ar.bulan',
     DATEPART(year, es.date_nilai) AS 'es.tahun',
     DATEPART(month, es.date_nilai) AS 'es.bulan'" );
    $this->db->from('employment e');
    $this->db->join('employment_job j', 'e.id = j.emp_id', 'INNER');
    $this->db->join('job_title jt', 'j.job_title = jt.id', 'INNER');
    $this->db->join('absen_rekap ar', 'ar.nik = e.nik', 'INNER');
    $this->db->join('evaluation_submission es', 'es.bulan = ar.bulan', 'INNER');
    $this->db->where('ar.tahun', 'es.tahun');
```

but still get an error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM (`employment` e) INNER JOIN `employment_job` j ON `e`.`id` = `j`.`emp_id` I' at line 2
>
> SELECT `e`.`fname`, `e`.`lname`, `e`.`nik`, `e`.`id`, `j`.`emp_id`, `j`.`job_title`, `jt`.`id`, `jt`.`name` AS jabatan, `ar`.`nik`, `DATEPART` (year, `ar`.`tanggal)` AS 'ar.tahun', DATEPART(month, `ar`.`tanggal)` AS 'ar.bulan', DATEPART(year, `es`.`date_nilai)` AS 'es.tahun', DATEPART(month, `es`.`date_nilai)` AS 'es.bulan' FROM (`employment` e) INNER JOIN `employment_job` j ON `e`.`id` = `j`.`emp_id` INNER JOIN `job_title` jt ON `j`.`job_title` = `jt`.`id` INNER JOIN `absen_rekap` ar ON `ar`.`nik` = `e`.`nik` INNER JOIN `evaluation_submission` es ON `es`.`bulan` = `ar`.`bulan` WHERE `ar`.`tahun` = 'es.tahun' GROUP BY `ar`.`nik` ORDER BY `e`.`fname` asc

I don't know what's wrong with my query ):

=======================================================================================
[update]

I change the code like the following :

```
function get_absenand_evaluation_submission_data_by_submission($id){
    
    $data = array();
    if ($this->evaluation_model->get_id_emp_by_subm_id($id))
    {
        $emp_data = $this->evaluation_model->get_id_emp_by_subm_id($id);
        foreach ($emp_data as $row)
            {
                    array_push($data, $row->emp_id);
            }
    }

    $this->db->select("e.fname, e.lname, e.nik, e.id, j.emp_id, j.job_title, jt.id, jt.name AS jabatan, ar.nik,
    DATEPART (year, ar.tanggal) AS 'ar.tahun',
     DATEPART(month,ar.tanggal) AS 'ar.bulan',
     DATEPART(year, es.date_nilai) AS 'es.tahun',
     DATEPART(month, es.date_nilai) AS 'es.bulan'" );
    $this->db->from('employment e');
    $this->db->join('employment_job j', 'e.id = j.emp_id', 'INNER');
    $this->db->join('job_title jt', 'j.job_title = jt.id', 'INNER');
    $this->db->join('absen_rekap ar', 'ar.nik = e.nik', 'INNER');
    $this->db->join('evaluation_submission es', 'es.bulan = ar.bulan', 'INNER');
    $this->db->where('ar.tahun = es.tahun');
    
    $this->db->group_by('ar.nik');
    $this->db->order_by('e.fname', 'asc');
    if ($data){
        $this->db->where_not_in('e.id',$data);
    }
    var_dump($this->db);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return $query->result();
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

I've tried the *var_dump($this->db);* , but it appeared like this :

```
object(CI_DB_mysql_driver)#13 (73) { ["dbdriver"]=> string(5) "mysql" ["_escape_char"]=> string(1) "`" ["_like_escape_str"]=> string(0) "" ["_like_escape_chr"]=> string(0) "" ["delete_hack"]=> bool(true) ["_count_string"]=> string(19) "SELECT COUNT(*) AS " ["_random_keyword"]=> string(7) " RAND()" ["use_set_names"]=> bool(false) ["ar_select"]=> array(17) { [0]=> string(7) "e.fname" [1]=> string(7) "e.lname" [2]=> string(5) "e.nik" [3]=> string(4) "e.id" [4]=> string(8) "j.emp_id" [5]=> string(11) "j.job_title" [6]=> string(5) "jt.id" [7]=> string(18) "jt.name AS jabatan" [8]=> string(6) "ar.nik" [9]=> string(14) "DATEPART (year" [10]=> string(25) "ar.tanggal) AS 'ar.tahun'" [11]=> string(14) "DATEPART(month" [12]=> string(25) "ar.tanggal) AS 'ar.bulan'" [13]=> string(13) "DATEPART(year" [14]=> string(28) "es.date_nilai) AS 'es.tahun'" [15]=> string(14) "DATEPART(month" [16]=> string(28) "es.date_nilai) AS 'es.bulan'" } ["ar_distinct"]=> bool(false) ["ar_from"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(14) "`employment` e" } ["ar_join"]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(56) "INNER JOIN `employment_job` j ON `e`.`id` = `j`.`emp_id`" [1]=> string(56) "INNER JOIN `job_title` jt ON `j`.`job_title` = `jt`.`id`" [2]=> string(53) "INNER JOIN `absen_rekap` ar ON `ar`.`nik` = `e`.`nik`" [3]=> string(68) "INNER JOIN `evaluation_submission` es ON `es`.`bulan` = `ar`.`bulan`" } ["ar_where"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(23) "`ar`.`tahun` = es.tahun" } ["ar_like"]=> array(0) { } ["ar_groupby"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "`ar`.`nik`" } ["ar_having"]=> array(0) { } ["ar_keys"]=> array(0) { } ["ar_limit"]=> bool(false) ["ar_offset"]=> bool(false) ["ar_order"]=> bool(false) ["ar_orderby"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(15) "`e`.`fname` asc" } ["ar_set"]=> array(0) { } ["ar_wherein"]=> array(0) { } ["ar_aliased_tables"]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(1) "e" [1]=> string(1) "j" [2]=> string(2) "jt" [3]=> string(2) "ar" [4]=> string(2) "es" } ["ar_store_array"]=> array(0) { } ["ar_caching"]=> bool(false) ["ar_cache_exists"]=> array(0) { } ["ar_cache_select"]=> array(0) { } ["ar_cache_from"]=> array(0) { } ["ar_cache_join"]=> array(0) { } ["ar_cache_where"]=> array(0) { } ["ar_cache_like"]=> array(0) { } ["ar_cache_groupby"]=> array(0) { } ["ar_cache_having"]=> array(0) { } ["ar_cache_orderby"]=> array(0) { } ["ar_cache_set"]=> array(0) { } ["ar_no_escape"]=> array(17) { [0]=> NULL [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL [3]=> NULL [4]=> NULL [5]=> NULL [6]=> NULL [7]=> NULL [8]=> NULL [9]=> NULL [10]=> NULL [11]=> NULL [12]=> NULL [13]=> NULL [14]=> NULL [15]=> NULL [16]=> NULL } ["ar_cache_no_escape"]=> array(0) { } ["username"]=> string(4) "root" ["password"]=> string(0) "" ["hostname"]=> string(9) "localhost" ["database"]=> string(3) "hrd" ["dbprefix"]=> string(0) "" ["char_set"]=> string(4) "utf8" ["dbcollat"]=> string(15) "utf8_general_ci" ["autoinit"]=> bool(true) ["swap_pre"]=> string(0) "" ["port"]=> string(0) "" ["pconnect"]=> bool(true) ["conn_id"]=> resource(32) of type (mysql link persistent) ["result_id"]=> resource(54) of type (mysql result) ["db_debug"]=> bool(true) ["benchmark"]=> float(0.0012531280517578) ["query_count"]=> int(3) ["bind_marker"]=> string(1) "?" ["save_queries"]=> bool(true) ["queries"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(58) "SELECT * FROM (`evaluation_submission`) WHERE `id` = '36'" [1]=> string(79) "SELECT * FROM (`evaluation_submission`) WHERE `id` = '36' AND `approve` = '1'" [2]=> string(96) "SELECT `ee`.`emp_id` FROM (`evaluation_record_employment` ee) WHERE `ee`.`submission_id` = '36'" } ["query_times"]=> array(3) { [0]=> float(0.00055599212646484) [1]=> float(0.00047612190246582) [2]=> float(0.00022101402282715) } ["data_cache"]=> array(0) { } ["trans_enabled"]=> bool(true) ["trans_strict"]=> bool(true) ["_trans_depth"]=> int(0) ["_trans_status"]=> bool(true) ["cache_on"]=> bool(false) ["cachedir"]=> string(0) "" ["cache_autodel"]=> bool(false) ["CACHE"]=> NULL ["_protect_identifiers"]=> bool(true) ["_reserved_identifiers"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "*" } ["stmt_id"]=> NULL ["curs_id"]=> NULL ["limit_used"]=> NULL ["stricton"]=> bool(false) }
```

What is that means?

Comment: For comparison, use `year()` and `month()` functions.

Answer (score 3):

You have a several syntax error in your code. Maybe this is not an answer, but for code formatting, I need to be use the answer box.

There is an unopened `*/` after

```
$this->db->join('job_title jt', 'j.job_title = jt.id', 'INNER');
```

You are closing the string here:

```
$this->db->select('e.fname,e.lname,e.nik,e.id, jt.name AS jabatan, ar.nik, ar.nilai',
```

so there will be syntax error too.

You have error in your sql, there is an unnecessary `,` at the end of your first query, and the quotes are wrong also:

```
$this->db->select("e.fname,e.lname,e.nik,e.id, jt.name AS jabatan, ar.nik, ar.nilai,
DATEPART (year, 'ar.tanggal') AS 'ar.tahun',
DATEPART(month, 'ar.tanggal') AS 'ar.bulan',
DATEPART(year, 'es.date_nilai') AS 'es.tahun'");
```

And you need to wrap your conditions at here:

```
$this->db->where("('ar.tahun', 'es.tahun') && ('ar.bulan', 'es.bulan')");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I still get an error after fixing my syntax. See my edited code above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$this->db->select("e.fname,e.lname,e.nik,e.id, jt.name AS jabatan, ar.nik, ar.nilai, 
        DATEPART (year, ar.tanggal) AS 'ar.tahun',
         DATEPART(month,ar.tanggal) AS 'ar.bulan',
         DATEPART(year, es.date_nilai) AS 'es.tahun',
         DATEPART(month, es.date_nilai) AS 'es.bulan'" );
```

You were using your quotes wrongly. For more information: [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Comment: I've tried it but I still get an error :( `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM (employment e) INNER JOIN employment_job j ON e.id = j.emp_id` 
See my edited code above.

Comment: Try `var_dump($this->db)` just to know how your query looks like, before you execute it.

Comment: Also, try `employment_job AS j` instead of `employment_job j`, and do this for all your tables

Comment: Another thing, your where clause is wrong: change it to: `$this->db->where('ar.tahun = es.tahun');`